# How to stop PHP from escaping apostrophes in a form

Tags: php, forms, escaping, apostrophe

I have a form, one input will contain the value: `Where something = 'something'`.

When I echo the `$_GET` (or `$_POST`) it replaces it with `Where something = \'something\'`

Any suggestions?

I thought it would be fixed with `urlencode` going into the form and `urldecode` when I echo it, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to turn off [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in php.ini.

Comment: ... and upgrade to a newer php. it should be off by default. it was a moronic idea from th very beginning.

Comment: Haha, funny you should say that Marc, as I was changing it I received a message from my hosting company that they were upgrading to 5.3 right now. I checked back and I was at 5.3, so had I waited 30 seconds to post this, it would have been 'fixed'. Only thing is, if I use 5.3 I cant edit the settings anymore ?!?!

Comment: @iight If you're still after a solution, one might be to use `str_replace` and replace any apostrophes with the relevant `ASCII` prior to selecting/inserting/updating anything from the database, for example `where something = '&#039;something&#039;'` and then PHP won't escape it. Regards